subscript and superscript on $\rangle$
I need to have something between angle brackets raised to a power, let's say the second power.
At the same time I want a subscript on the closing bracket a little lower than _ allows for.
This last problem is solved by Steven B. Segletesin Subscript on $\rangle$ by making use of the stackengine package. But this solution does not fit well with a ^ following it, as instead _ does: the subscript happens to be too much far on the right.
To recap:
\langle A\rangle_X^2
is not good because subscript X appears at a higher position than expected
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\subrangle#1{\stackengine{5pt}{}{$\!\scriptstyle #1$}{U}{l}{F}{F}{L}}

\begin{document}
  $\langle A\rangle_{X}^2$
  
  $\langle A\rangle\subrangle{X}^2$
\end{document}

is not good because superscript 2 appears shifted on the right with respect to the expected position.
How to solve this?

Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at our starter guide to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I got it. Thank you for your advices

You can test for the presence of subscripts and superscripts:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\angled}{me{^_}}{%
  \langle #1\rangle
  ^{\smash[t]{\mathstrut}\IfValueT{#2}{#2}}% superscript
  _{\smash[b]{\mathstrut}\IfValueT{#3}{\!#3}}% subscript
}

\begin{document}

$\langle A\rangle_{X}^{2}$
$\angled{A}_{X}^{2}$
$\angled{A}^{2}$
$\angled{A}_{X}$

\end{document}



without words! really thank you

@egreg May I ask, what is the me in the definition of \angled?

@bishopcranmer m stands for a mandatory argument; e stands for arguments preceded by the following characters, in any order. You find the full explanation in usrguide.pdf

Does this meet your needs?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\subrangle#1{\stackengine{5pt}{}{$\!\scriptstyle #1$}{U}{l}{F}{F}{L}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myangle}{me{_^}}{\langle #1 \rangle\stackanchor[5pt]{\IfValueT{#3}{$\!\scriptstyle #3$}}{\IfValueT{#2}{$\!\scriptstyle #2$}}}

\begin{document}
  $\langle A\rangle_{X}^2$
  
  $\langle A\rangle\subrangle{X}^2$
  
  $\myangle{A}_{X+y}^2+1$
  
  $\myangle{A}^2+2$
  
  $\myangle{A}^{3+x}+2$
  
  $\myangle{A}_{X}+3$
  
\end{document}


